# Extending objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to angularjs.  I'm looking for a way to return objects for extending from a factory that ARE NOT singletons. This way, people can't muck with the object data higher up in the application stack.  This is what I've come up with so far, is it correct? Or is there a better way?

```
angular.module('utils', [])
.factory('extendableOject', function () {

  return function () {
    return {
      prop1 : 1,
      func1 : function () {
        this.prop1++;
      }
    };
  } ();
});
```

Comment: I believe this is OK.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
angular.module('utils', [])
.factory('extendableOject', function () {

  return function () {
    return {
      prop1 : 1,
      func1 : function () {
        this.prop1++;
      }
    };
  };
});
```

I should not have been invoking the function from within the factory.  That would have been no different than just returning the object itself.  With the above code, I can call "extendableObject()" from anywhere to retrieve a fresh instance.

Comment: By this, I assume you mean my original question :)

Comment: Yes, I should be more explicit: Those parentheses in the *original* post were wrong (as you correctly figured out) and I totally missed them.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thanks for taking a look, and also confirming that my 'method' is correct. :)